# Javascript call to function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

IF a word is clicked on the screen 
the javascript should display the sentence which has the word.
Now this is what i have done 
 jsfiddle. net /qgkj9pxp/

I have two functions. First is to find the word clicked on which is

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function () {
    $("body").click(function () {
        // Gets clicked on word (or selected text if text is selected)
        var t = '';
        var nstr = '';
        if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
            // Webkit, Gecko
            var s = window.getSelection();
            if (s.isCollapsed) {
                s.modify('move', 'forward', 'character');
                s.modify('move', 'backward', 'word');
                s.modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');
                t = s.toString();
                s.modify('move', 'forward', 'character'); //clear selection
            } else {
                t = s.toString();
            }
        } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
            // IE 4+
            var textRange = sel.createRange();
            if (!textRange.text) {
                textRange.expand("word");
            }
            // Remove trailing spaces
            while (/\s$/.test(textRange.text)) {
                textRange.moveEnd("character", -1);
            }
            t = textRange.text;

        }

        t = t.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        isThere(t);


    });
    
});

//]]>
```

And the second function which is called by the first function to check which sentence the clicked on word is.

```js
function isThere(f) {
    var str = "Big data is a broad term for data sets so large or complex that traditional data processing applications are inadequate. Challenges include analysis, capture, data curation, search, sharing, storage, transfer, visualization, and information privacy. The term often refers simply to the use of predictive analytics or other certain advanced methods to extract value from data, and seldom to a particular size of data set. Accuracy in big data may lead to more confident decision making. And better decisions can mean greater operational efficiency, cost reduction and reduced risk. Analysis of data sets can find new correlations, to spot business trends, prevent diseases, combat crime and so on.Scientists, business executives, practitioners of media and advertising and governments alike regularly meet difficulties with large data sets in areas including Internet search, finance and business informatics. Scientists encounter limitations in e-Science work, including meteorology, genomics, connectomics, complex physics simulations and biological and environmental research. Work with big data is necessarily uncommon; most analysis is of PC size data, on a desktop PC or notebook that can handle the available data set.";

    var spli = str.split('.');
    var len = spli.length;
    var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var s = spli[i].split(" ");
        for (j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
            if (s[j] === f) 
                alert(spli[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly help me out and tell me why the second function is not working?

Comment: Put your code here. There's a reason you had to put spaces in the Fiddle link, and you going around it angers Tony the Pony.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a scavenger hunt.  Please include relevant information in the question itself, rather than clues and hints that you want us to piece together for you.

Comment: Ya sorry. Joins this forum just minutes back.
Ill do as you asked. Give me a sec to figure out stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you have

```
j === f
```

it should be

```
s[j] === f
```

Otherwise you're comparing a number to a word.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Typo. I have done that already. Still doesn;t seem to produce an ouput. Refer to the updated jsfiddle . net / qgkj9pxp